# Link validator points to wrong link

Tags: bug, edits, hyperlinks, broken-link

I edited this answer with an improved version today:
[Function to INSERT dynamic list of columns in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149387/function-to-insert-dynamic-list-of-columns-in-multiple-tables/11170583#11170583)

When trying to submit I got an error message from the link validator:

> ```
> Links to ... are not allowed
> ```

Consider the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of misleading error msg]

Took me some time to figure out that the broken one was actually link **[2]**, not [4].
Two aspects of the error message were confusing:

- It pointed to a valid, unrelated link.
- It referred to the wrong number in the appended link list.

It looks like the validator got confused by the later appearance of a correct instance to the same URL?

Note that the missing `5` for the last link is just an artefact from my attempts to debug the problem. I got the same error message with `5` present.

Comment: It *did* point to the right link, it just unencoded the `http://%20%20%5B4%5D:%20` part in the message (which wasn't helpful of it)

Comment: @TimStone: Ah, I see now: `http://%20%20%5B4%5D:%20` is just URL-encoded `http:// [4] ` ... tricky :). Well, unecoding wasn't really helpful, I can subscribe to that.

Comment: @TimStone: So .. delete the question or leave it as a reminder that decoding URLs may not be helpful?

Comment: Well, I do think it's a bug that the message doesn't match your actual input, so I'd leave it in the hopes that they'll fix it.